# Replacing proxyAddresses values

Tags: c#, active-directory, multiple-value

We have a c# script that needs to update/replace the proxyAddresses contents. 
I believe I understand how to add a range of values as follows:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(myConnectString);
DirectorySearcher Dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
Dsearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + theUser + ")";
SearchResult result = Dsearch.FindOne();
if (result != null)
{
 if (result.Properties.Contains("proxyAddresses"))
 {
   DirectoryEntry Uentry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
   Uentry.Properties[proxyAddresses].AddRange(new object[] {"user1@domain.com", "user2@domain.com"});
   Uentry.CommitChanges();
 }
}
```

However- feel free to correct any errors in the above code.  If this looks correct - my understanding is that AddRange will append my new values rather than replacing the current values.  Can someone please describe how I can remove/replace the existing contents of proxyAddresses with these new values..?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will replace the `proxyAddresses` properties

```
Uentry.Properties["proxyAddresses"].value = new object[] {"user1@domain.com", "user2@domain.com"};
```

There are more [**examples about how to work with proxyAddresses here**](http://geekswithblogs.net/mhamilton/archive/2005/12/18/63468.aspx)

Comment: Will this replace the existing content of proxyAddresses or just append to it?

Comment: @dev it will *replace it*

Comment: The code is wrong, and someone rejected my edit.  You need quotes around the property name.

Comment: it should be Uentry.Properties["proxyAddresses"].Value = ....